# Google Play Games Signs Out Automatically without Internet Unity

Tags: unity, c#, android, google-play-services

I am using [this](https://github.com/claywilkinson/AutoSaveUnitySample) in my game to implement games saving and loading.
I have also tried the basic sign in process by using the following start function :-

```
{

        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder ()
        // enables saving game progress.
        .EnableSavedGames ()
        .Build ();

        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance (config);
        // recommended for debugging:
        PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
        // Activate the Google Play Games platform
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate ();

        Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => {
            if (success){
                MyAutoSave.isLoaded = false;
            }
        });
    }

}`
```

I can sign in on google play games without any issues. Soon after that if I quit the game and start again without data connection, it gets authenticated without any issue.
If my data connection remains off for say more than an hour, and I start the game without Internet connection, there is no authentication whatsoever. If I close the game and start again soon after that, it gives me that google play games sign in popup. So what i can conclude is that it signs out automatically after some time if there is no Internet available. Is there any fix for this.?
Thanks